How to set System variable in a Java app?
I saw an article which suggested me to use--- Only by setting the default JAXB provider to be the glassfish implementation by setting the system property: jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContextFactory=org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.ContextFactory CXF will work in this setting.
How do I set this property?
I tried using
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContextFactory>org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.ContextFactory</jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContextFactory>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

but this did not work.

where to add the maven tag

Can you get this to work outside of Maven?  In other words, can you start GlassFish from the commandline, and tell it to use CXF?  Because if you can, then you'll know what to look for in Maven's output, to see if that plugin sets the -D parameter correctly.

"I tried using" "but this did not work." it is not much information for us to go with since a plugin element can be added in different sections of a POM file. So showing how your pom file is defined would help.

Why do you use old versions of plugins... Upgrade  to most recent versions: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/ Also without the full pom file it's hard to even guess what can be wrong?
